Min max problem with a bilinear form
My goal is to solve the problem
$\min_y \max_x y^T Ax$ with constraints $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$ and $\sum x_i = \sum y_i = 1$
($x,y$ are probability measures)
Is there a general way to solve this?
Actually I am given the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&3\\1&-1&0\\4&2&8\end{pmatrix}$$
Maybe for this matrix there is a specific trick
I tried to use a Lagrangien for $f(\cdot, y)$ but it seems to lead nowhere

Some thoughts.
For your matrix, we have
$$y^\top A x = (y_1 + y_2 + 4y_3)x_1
+ (-y_1 - y_2 + 2y_3)x_2 + (3y_1 + 8y_3)x_3.
$$
We have
$$\max_{x} y^\top Ax 
= \max\{y_1 + y_2 + 4y_3,\, -y_1-y_2 + 2y_3,\, 3y_1 + 8y_3\}.$$
Thus, it is equivalent to the following convex optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{y} \quad t\\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\quad y_1 + y_2 + y_3 \le t, \\
 &\qquad -y_1 - y_2 + 2y_3 \le t, \\
 &\qquad 3y_1 + 8y_3 \le t,\\
 &\qquad y_1, y_2, y_3 \ge 0,\quad y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 1.
\end{align*}

Not just convex but linear.

@RobPratt Yes, it is linear.
